# Problem with Tutorial link

Tags: ros, documentation, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've been documenting the following package on ROS.org: [patrolling_sim](http://www.ros.org/wiki/patrolling_sim).

My next step would be to write a tutorial. I looked into *How to Write a Tutorial* page. There, it says "In the sidebar of the page there will be a link for tutorials". However, i did not find such link.

Therefore, I made some navigation bar magic and went to the imaginary page:
[http://www.ros.org/wiki/patrolling_sim/Tutorials/Run patrolling_sim](http://www.ros.org/wiki/patrolling_sim/Tutorials/Run patrolling_sim) and created my tutorial with the name "Run patrolling_sim".

After I finished the tutorial, I noticed that it wasn't related to my package. Instead, it has gone to the following link:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/%40PAGE%40/Run%20patrolling_sim

Obviously, I made a mistake in the process. Can someone help me move the tutorial in order to be linked with my package? Beyond not being able to move the tutorial, I was not also able to delete it (to later create a new one related to the package).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12248/problem-with-tutorial-link/) by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 349 on 2011-12-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, so I basically created the tutorial again, now in the correct place.

I just need someone with privileges at ROS.org to delete the initial tutorial:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/%40PAGE%40/Run%20patrolling_sim

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) with karma: 349 on 2011-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-12-10**:
You're right to just create the Tutorial page in the location.  We changed the sidebar to not show the dead link if the page doesn't exist.  If you just create PACKAGE_NAME/Tutorials page the link should become active.  I've cleaned up the extra wiki page you created.